# regex to extract number in range

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract numbers from 1 to 19 from the given string.

```
String n="1 21 16 17 9 8 22 20 10";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(1[0-9]|[0-9])");
Matcher m=p.matcher(n);
while(m.find())
    System.out.println(n.substring(m.start(),m.end()));
}
```

Output I obtain:

```
 1
 2
 1
 16
 17
 9
 8
 2
 2
 2
 0
10
```

Expected output should ignore `20`, `21`, `22` from the string. Right now, instead of that, `22` gets split into `2` and `2`  in the display which is not expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add word boundaries:

```
String n="1 21 16 17 9 8 22 20 10";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("\\b(1[0-9]|[0-9])\\b");
Matcher m=p.matcher(n);
while(m.find())
    System.out.println(n.substring(m.start(),m.end()));
}
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/CAnLkm)

Answer (score 6):

Use word boundaries:

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("\\b(1[0-9]|[0-9])\\b");
```